# Is it possible to add a validation attribute to a function parameter after the function has already been created?

Tags: powershell

I found [this method](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2013/05/hacking-validateset.html) of dynamically updating the validate set members of a parameter.

This let's me do something like this:

```
Function MyFunction([ValidateSet("Placeholder")]$Param1) { "$Param1" }
Update-ValidateSet -Command (Get-Command MyFunction) -ParameterName "Param1" -NewSet @("red","green")
```

But is there any way of *adding* a validation attribute that was not already present? Specifically, I have a set of functions that would benefit greatly by having dynamically created validate sets. However, as the link above makes clear, this is a hack, and may break in the future. So I don't want to put a placeholder ValidateSet, in case it needs to be removed in the future. Essentially, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Function MyFunction($Param1) { "Param1" }
Add-ValidateSet -Command (Get-Command MyFunction) -ParameterName "Param1" -NewSet @("red", "green")
```

This way, if it ever does break, it would be easier to remove the breaking code. But I have not been able to get this to work. I've tried doing this:

```
$parameter = (Get-Command MyFunction).Parameters["P1"]
$set = "Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet"
$Attribute = new-object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute $Set
$ValidValuesField = [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute].GetField("validValues", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)
$ValidValuesField.SetValue($Attribute, [string[]]$Set)
$parameter.Attributes.Add($Attribute)
```

But it does not work.

```
(Get-Command MyFunction).Parameters["P1"].Attributes
```

shows that the ValidateSet has been added, but tab completion does not work. Comparing it with the results of using the Update-ValidateSet function, it appears that the difference is that the attribute should also appear under

```
(Get-Command MyFunction).ParameterSets[0].Parameters[0].Attributes
```

However, that is a ReadOnlyCollection, so I don't seem to be able to add it there. Am I just barking up the wrong tree here? Is this not possible to do?

Comment: Parameter metadata is supposed to be readonly, otherwise you could cause some really hard to debug problems.

Comment: @rerun has a nice solution that I never considered before, but it works nicely for some scenarios.  Dynamic parameters aren't perfect though, so you may hit some issues.  If the ultimate goal is good TabExpansion, another option is to just extend TabExpansion.  See http://www.github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus for a nice way to do that.

Comment: TabExpansionPlusPlus might be exactly what I need. I'll have to play around with the performance of it versus using dynamic parameters, but either way, it looks like I'll be able to do what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accomplish this using dynamic parameters.  The dynamic parameters will be evaluated as your command is typed into the command window.

This is from [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

```
function Get-Sample {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param ([String]$Name, [String]$Path)

        DynamicParam
        {
            if ($path -match ".*HKLM.*:")
            {
                $attributes = new-object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
                $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
                $attributes.Mandatory = $false
                $attributeCollection = new-object `
                    -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
                $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

                $dynParam1 = new-object `
                    -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("dp1", [Int32], $attributeCollection)

                $paramDictionary = new-object `
                    -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
                $paramDictionary.Add("dp1", $dynParam1)
                return $paramDictionary
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this will help me do what I need.